# is it good to create index on varchar field containing comma separated values?

Tags: mysql

I was creating a small database which would store good amount of data.
The table is having a column which will store foreign keys in varchar format (e.g. 1,12,13...) so that I could get the data all in one go.
So, will it matter if I indexed the column to the primary key of the master table. 
(I am only indexing and not creating foreign key reference )

Comment: If you really store multiple integer values in one varchar column, then that's definitely wrong! Read about normalization and change your schema design.

Comment: That's all irrelevant. You need to: Create application architecture which corresponds to your business logic. Then, define precise DB structure according to chosen architecture. Finally, decide which queries will be done often and what is more important. Only after that you may think of some sort of optimization

Comment: Adding an index on such a column won't help you at all. Change your db structure like fancyPants said.

Comment: You can easily get all the data in one go without using a comma separated list of foreign keys (which is generally a really bad idea). Have a link table if needs be with a single row per foreign key per item. An index can help, but in your situation if you wanted to find items with a foreign key of 12 it would be useless.

Comment: Actually the data is not much useful, i mean i finding it useless to create another table just to store only the temporary data.

Comment: But, this might be used for reporting section. So, i was thinking of using FIND_IN_SET() to get the necessary report. Will that create impact on performance?

Comment: FIND_IN_SET is useful, but can't use any indexes so will not be fast. Indexes on varchars work (in general) like the alphabetic index of a phone directory. Using the phone book analogy if you know the surname you can easily find the page containing people with that surname. If you were looking for people where the 2nd letter of their surname is a particular letter then the index is useless as you need to check every single entry in the book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To explain the indexes a bit, take the following example.

Categories

```
Id  Category
1   Cat A
2   Cat B
3   Cat C
4   Cat D
5   Cat E
6   Cat F
```

Users

```
Id  Name    CategoryList
1   Bill    1,2,3
2   Burt    4,5,6
3   Jill    1,3,5
4   Alli    2,4,6
```

If there is an index on the categories field in the users table if would be something like this:-

```
1,2,3   1
1,3,5   3
2,4,6   4
4,5,6   2
```

If you look for "1,3,5" then it is easy to search that table in order and find the matching ids. It can (for example) jump to half way through the index and check if the value it is looking for is higher or lower. Then repeat that process to find the records it want.

However if you search for a row containing the category 2 (as below) then as 2 could be at any point in the string the index can't be used.

```
SELECT Users.Name, Categories.Category
FROM Users
INNER JOIN Categories
ON FIND_IN_SET(Category.Id, Users.CategoryList)
WHERE Categories.Category = 2
```

FIND_IN_SET can't use an index as the values it is checking could be at any point in that comma separated list. Instead it has to check every single row and look for one which has a comma separated value of 2. This is certainly going to be more efficient that manually splitting up the string in SQL (which is possible), but slow compared to using an index.

For example, if you had 1000 rows each with 1000 comma separated ids, and you wanted the single row that has the id 123 in its list then FIND_IN_SET needs to read 1000 rows, split every one of those rows up and check those values to be 123, so 1000000 comparions (plus the processing to split the comma separated lists up). If the id is on its own in an indexed field it is doing close to 1 comparison.

If instead the tables were:-

Categories

```
Id  Category
1   Cat A
2   Cat B
3   Cat C
4   Cat D
5   Cat E
6   Cat F
```

Users

```
Id  Name    
1   Bill    
2   Burt    
3   Jill    
4   Alli
```

UsersCategories

```
Id  UserId  CatId
1   1       1
2   1       2
3   1       3
4   2       4
5   2       5       
6   2       6
7   3       1
8   3       3
9   3       5
10  4       2
11  4       4
12  4       6
```

The you can have an index on the integer fields (which will be fast) and you could simply do a join:-

```
SELECT Users.Name, Categories.Category
FROM Categories
INNER JOIN UsersCategories
ON Categories.Id = UsersCategories.CatId
INNER JOIN Users
ON UsersCategories.UserId = Users.Id
WHERE Categories.Category = 2
```

This can easily use an index on each of the comparisons / joins to give respectable performance.

EDIT - Following will give you a list of all the users and for each one a list of the categories they have:-

```
SELECT Users.Name, GROUP_CONCAT(Categories.Category)
FROM Users
LEFT OUTER JOIN UsersCategories
ON UsersCategories.UserId = Users.Id
LEFT OUTER JOIN Categories
ON Categories.Id = UsersCategories.CatId
GROUP BY Users.Name
```

Comment: nice explaination @kickstart ty.

Comment: What if i don't want to assign category to user, but still i want it to be displayed in the list?
How the query would be?

Comment: This query was written for those who do have a particular category (ie, 2). Do you want a query that displays all users, with something to show those which are in that particular category? Or do you want to limit the list of users in some other way?

Comment: I want to display the list of all users along with their categories, even if the category is not assigned to it.
if category is not assigned, display the category as NA.

Comment: I would've thought that the index should rather look like this (each value/word associated with the row id where it can be found)
1   1,3  \n
2   1,4  \n
3   1,3  \n
4   2,4  \n
5   2,3  \n
6   2,4  \n

Comment: @DanielKatz - that is still an index which would require searching. Hence if you want to know which categories that a particular user is linked to would mean searching every single index entry - it wouldn't use the indexes for this, it would just ignore them and read every row.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL having an index on VARCHAR is supported so you can go ahead and create that.

However there is a constraint on the amount of space MysqL sets asides for Indexes which can be up to 1000 bytes long for MyISAM and 767 bytes for InnoDB tables. So in the event where your data grows the index might not be supported and will not be used efficiently. Possible explanation can be found at:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-indexes.html

In case you want some alternative approaches to deal with your database, you can give this post a read:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35821/possible-index-on-a-varchar-field-in-mysql